# Is SQLFairy/SQL::Translator offer support for visualizing SQL Server 2012 databases?

Tags: sql-server, perl, sqlfairy

the documentation seems to be somewhat out of date (last edit was in 2007), and a quick look through related forums shows a few references to this problem:

https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=90700

is anyone using SQLFairy to visualize a modern version of SQLServer? Is this supported/meant to work at all?